# &nbsp; converting to Â in text boxes and editor primefaces 5.3

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I am using editor of primefaces to show some text which contains `&nbsp;` on first page load it shows it correctly but if user presses back button all the `&nbsp;` gets converted to `Â`. I have tried putting below meta tag on the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

I have also tried to put the text in text boxes which also shows same error.

primefaces version is 5.3

```
<p:editor id="testProcedure" value="#{app.editText}" controls="underline bold italic" style="width:1016px;margin-left:10px;border:1px solid grey;"></p:editor>
```

This is happening if I use commandButton with type submit. but I cannot remove type submit because my data do not submit completely without it

Comment: Is this the same in all browsers you've tested with? Browsers can be configured to override the charset info they receive from the page.

Comment: yes its the same for all browsers

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try with the [<f:view />](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/view.html) wrapping all the `head` and `body` tags:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8">
        <h:head>
            <title>Facelet Title</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            Hello from Facelets
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Please state **why** you think this would solve things.